# Remove-SPOSite : The label that's applied to this item prevents it from being edited or deleted. Check the item's label for more details

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, site, sharepoint-admin-center

trying to delete a site but it simply does not work, from the UI, from powershell, etc.

> Remove-SPOSite : The label that's applied to this item prevents it
> from being edited or deleted. Check the item's label for more details.

the site is empty, no custom libraries, nothing inside them, no retention.
no AAD group, no team.

ticket open, not much help so far

anyone knows how to look for this "label"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently there was in fact a retention label applied to one of the libraries, but not visible through the user interface (library settings > apply label to items in this list or library)

the fix

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Url -Interactive
Get-PnPList | ForEach { Write-Host $_.Title; Get-PnPLabel -List $_.Title; Reset-PnPLabel -List $_.Title}
```